# How to use imtoolkit (precompiled/source) for Chicken Scheme?

Tags: compilation, chicken-scheme, iup

In order to use `iup` in Chicken Scheme, I need to provide some dependencies. One of them is IM (imtoolkit), which I found on https://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/cd/en/building.html , where it links me to [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imtoolkit/files/). From there I can download the source code to compile myself, but there are no instructions I could find how to do that and there is not the typical `configure` `make` `make install` structure, because there is no runnable `configure`. So I decided to use the precompiled version.

When I run `sudo chicken-install iup` I get the error:

```
iup.c:17:16: fatal error: im.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

So I know I need IM somewhere. It is not in the repositories. In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40560168/1829329), I learned about specifying a path to a library when using `chicken-install`. This makes the command I try using `CSC_OPTIONS=-I/home/xiaolong/development/ChickenScheme/IM/pr‌​ecompiled/include chicken-install -p ~/.chicken-scheme/eggs/ iup`. However, still it results in the same error.

How can I use the precompiled library?

Note: Compiling it myself is still not totally out of the picture, if I could find any instructions on how to do it.

## Info

- OS: Xubuntu 16.04 64bit
- Chicken Scheme version installed from the repositories:

  ```
  CHICKEN
  (c) 2008-2014, The Chicken Team
  (c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
  Version 4.9.0.1 (stability/4.9.0) (rev 8b3189b)
  linux-unix-gnu-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
  bootstrapped 2014-06-07
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try [this Makefile](http://www.kiatoa.com/cgi-bin/fossils/megatest/raw/utils/Makefile.installall?name=981091d91cd74d3815d832187d4e08) by Matthew Welland, for the Megatest UI.  It's the only way I've ever got iup to work at all (on an Ubuntu box).  Unfortunately, the Makefile is quite complex and it does a lot more than just install iup.

From what I can gather, it indeed downloads all the pre-built binaries of iup, im (imtoolkit) and cd (canvas draw), and it extracts them **all into the same directory**. Finally, it manually copies include files and shared objects around into the CHICKEN prefix. That's not exactly a best practice, but if it helps to get things up and running, maybe you can give it a shot. My advice would be to do it in a VM first, to avoid making too much of a mess on your main system.